# Flutter Clipboard option not showing in TextInputField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, clipboard, flutter-textinputfield

Here I am getting two problems:

- When I long press on TextInputField, I want here clipboard option which I am not getting to paste text from **ClipBoard**
- Selected Text is not visible.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: I think, selected text is not invisible here. The colors are the same as white. That is the issue!

Comment: I have not set Text Color to while, Its by default I am getting.

Comment: If you set your text color to red, you will see the selected text too. I'm searching for changing the color of the selection right now.

Comment: Okay great, I will let you know If I found something.

Comment: @Akif I have sent you linkedin connection with solution. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the selected color. You can add the color of the theme selected. **textSelectionHandleColor**

```
MaterialApp(
  
    theme: ThemeData(
      textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.blue[400],
      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    ),
   
    ),
```